# Angular 4 - Load Firebase auth parameters from config file

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm building an **Angular 4** app with Firebase, I do not want to save my **Firebase** configuration/initialization parameters in my `app.modules.ts` file, as this file is to be committed to my repo. In dev mode, I was able to save the setting using `export default {firebase {...}}` in a `config.ts` file and load the params from there.  However, when I build using **Angular CLI**, these parameters are not loaded.

The solutions I've found online so far, all work as services, but I need to be able to load these parameters when importing modules in my `AppModules` class.

Any ideas please?

Best regards,

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. Final solution based on a suggestion from a kind hearted soul :) was.

```
import { FirebaseConfigInterface } from './interfaces/firebase-config.interface';

export class AppConfig {
    public static site = {
        meta_title: null,
        app_id: null
    };

    public static firebaseConfig: FirebaseConfigInterface = {
        apiKey: null,
        authDomain: null,
        databaseURL: null,
        storageBucket: null,
        messagingSenderId: null
    }
};
```

I imported `AppConfig` to access it's static variables.

```
import {AppConfig} from './app.config';
```